# (Java) Converting String of symbols to single digit integer array

Tags: java, parsing, processing

I'm trying to take a String, i.e. `$!#`, convert each individual symbol to its corresponding ASCII value, it here being `36, 33, 35` and then ending up with an array of integers with each single number stored in a separate index, meaning `3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 5`.

In short: From `$!#` to `$,!,#` to `36, 33, 35` to `3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 5`

Since I am using Processing (wrapper for Java), my SO-research got me so far:

```
String str = "$!#";
byte[] b = str.getBytes();

for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
 println(b[i]); 
}
```

I'm ending up with the ASCII values. The byte array `b` contains `[36, 33, 35]`.

Now if those were to be Strings instead of bytes, I would use String.valueOf(b) to get `363335` and then split the whole thing again into a single digit integer array.

I wonder if this approach is unnecessarily complicated and can be done with less  conversion steps. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can just process each character, e.g. `$` -> `36` -> `3,6`

Comment: Are you sure that no input character has ASCII value > 99 ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it **seems inefficient**? How are you defining efficiency? What makes you believe your performance is poor? How large are your `String` values? What context is this code running in?

Comment: @Kevin: I meant as little data type conversions as possible, since I was unsure.

Comment: @rkosegi: I'm fine with 0–99 for my project's proof of concept. But this is an obvious point for further improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, if I were you, I wouldn't worry too much about "efficiency" until you have an actual problem. Write code that you understand. If you have a problem with efficiency, you'll have to define exactly what you mean: is it taking too many steps? Is it taking too long? What is the size of your input?

Note that the approach you outlined and the approach below are both O(N), which is probably the best you're going to get.

If you have a specific bottleneck inside that O(N) then you should do some profiling to figure out where that is. But you shouldn't bother with micro-optimizations (or *shudder* premature optimizations) just because you "feel" like something is "inefficient".

To quote from [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/114262):

> ...in the absence of measured performance issues you shouldn't optimize because you **think** you will get a performance gain.

If I were you, I would just use the `charAt()` function to get each `char` in the `String`, and then use the `int()` function to convert that `char` into an `int`. Then you could add those `int` values to a `String` (or better yet, a `StringBuilder`):

```
String str = "$!#";

StringBuilder digits = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
  int c = int(str.charAt(i));
  digits.append(c);
}
```

Then you could use the `split()` function to split them into individual digits:

```
String[] digitArray = digits.toString().split("");
for (String d : digitArray) {
  println(d);
}
```

Prints:

```
3
6
3
3
3
5
```

There are a ton of different ways to do this: you could use the `toCharArray()` function instead of `charAt()`, for example. But none of this is going to be any more or less "efficient" until you define exactly what you mean by efficiency.

Comment: He wants it to be an array of `int[]` such as `3,6,3,3,3,5`, and not `36,33,35`.

Comment: "These approaches are all O(N), which is probably the best you're going to get.". Rather obvious that you can't do better than that. You have to look at each character at least once after all.

Comment: @Voo Yep, exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin, this solved my problem. What I meant by efficiency was less "steps" of converting. As my knowledge of programming is humble, I wasn't sure if I was overcomplicating things. This might seem secondary when new to programming, yet I do respect an elegant solution and try to learn from that. But you're right, I should've focused on solving the problem, before prematurely optimizing the approach.

Comment: @pmish No problem. It can be tempting to get hung up on finding the "best" solution, but 95% of programming is just getting it done and moving on. That being said, the approach you take for a `String` with 100 characters might be different from the approach you take for a `String` with a trillion characters. But since your context is probably closer to the `100` mark, oftentimes the simplest solution (and therefore easiest to understand) is the best option.

Comment: **One last addition:** Since I initially asked to end up with an `integer array`, this is what I changed Kevin's second code block into: `int[] intArray = int(digits.toString().split(""));`. This provides the necessary data type.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 stream solution:

```
int[] digits = "$!#".chars()
                    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                    .flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)
                    .map(c -> c - '0')
                    .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits)); // prints [3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Note that this is a [tag:processing] question, and Processing does not support Java 8. Also, is this "more efficient" than OP's solution, or is it just hiding the O(N) inside the stream API? I'm not saying your question is wrong (in fact I always like to see Java 8 solutions), but you might want to include this info in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be doing something like that

```
// Create an array of int of a size 3 * str.length()

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
  int n = (int) str.charAt(i);
  int a = n / 100;
  int b = (n - (a * 100)) / 10;
  int c = n - (a * 100) - (b * 10);

  // push a, b and c in your array (chose the order and if you want
  // to add the potential 0's or not)
}
```

But as others said before, I'm not sure if it worth playing like that. It depends on your application I guess.